# Read & change a SELECT (HTML) from Terminal

Tags: bash, select, terminal

I want to do two tasks but I don't know how:

1. Read from terminal the value of a select? I know the name of the **select** and all the options of this **select**. I can't change the web and I need to access this data through terminal.
2. Change the value of this select with a valid option using Terminal too.

I tried with `wget www.webpage.com/index.html?selectname=` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What mean by "access"? You can fetch the full page with wget for example, or by pure bash:

```
url="$1"
uri=($(echo "$url" | sed 's~http://\([^/][^/]*\)\(.*\)~\1 \2~'))
HOST=${uri[0]:=localhost}
FILE=${uri[1]:=/}
exec {SOCKET}<>/dev/tcp/$HOST/80
echo -ne "GET $FILE HTTP/1.1\nHost: $HOST\n\n" >&${SOCKET}
<&${SOCKET} sed -e '1,/^.$/d'
```

If you want browsing from terminal, try "[lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29)".

Honestly, have no idea what you mean with: *I can't change the web and I need to access this data through terminal.*

And in the 2.: *Change the value of this select with a valid option using Terminal too.* **How change**? Want change the source of the html? Or you mean submit the form with some select(ed)-value?

Submitting a form maybe easy or not. Depends on several factors. It is GET or POST? What is the FORM's submit url? etc.. etc...

Or want something other?

Is is impossible answer your question in this form.

Comment: sorry access it's not correct, the word is read the selected value in a select.

Comment: Selected value "by default"? Not an easy task, because it can be done with html (<OPTION VALUE="aaa" SELECTED>, or by javascript too.

Comment: No, know the selected value in a select and how to change the selected to other. I don't want to see the page, only read or change values on a select or a box.

Comment: Submitting a select can be done by more ways - depending how the page is constructed. Here is no universal answer. Basically, need figure out the url, to where the select is submitted and after you can construct the right http-request.

Comment: Ok. Could you put an easy example. I saw the webpage where is the data and the submit button is like this, <input type="submit" value="Save" width="75"> I don't know how to start. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Best what you can do: edit your question, put inside the relevant part of html and _maybe_ will be possible give an easy answer.